# How do I convert hex to binary (and vice versa) in Ruby, WHILE maintaining leading zeroes?

Tags: ruby, binary, hex

I have a data structure that I'd like to convert back and forth from hex to binary in Ruby. The simplest approach for a binary to hex is '0010'.to_i(2).to_s(16) - unfortunately this does not preserve leading zeroes (due to the to_i call), as one may need with data structures like cryptographic keys (which also vary with the number of leading zeroes).

Is there an easy built in way to do this?

Comment: In general, cryptographic keys are just integers (or pairs of integers), and the most natural way to express them in Ruby is using the built-in Integer class.  Separately, you should also keep track of the upper limit of these integers in terms of how many bits they can hold, and perhaps use that when you converting these integers to and from various ASCII or binary formats.  Trying to store your keys as a string with leadings zeros, where the leading zeros actually make a difference to your program, seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should have a firm idea of how many bits are in your cryptographic key.  That should be stored in some constant or variable in your program, not inside individual strings representing the key:

```
KEY_BITS = 16
```

The most natural way to represent a key is as an integer, so if you receive a key in a hex format you can convert it like this (leading zeros in the string do not matter):

```
key = 'a0a0'.to_i(16)
```

If you receive a key in a (ASCII) binary format, you can convert it like this (leading zeros in the string do not matter):

```
key = '101011'.to_i(2)
```

If you need to output a key in hex with the right number of leading zeros:

```
key.to_s(16).rjust((KEY_BITS+3)/4, '0')
```

If you need to output a key in binary with the right number of leading zeros:

```
key.to_s(2).rjust(KEY_BITS, '0')
```

If you really do want to figure out how many bits might be in a key based on a (ASCII) binary or hex string, you can do:

```
key_bits = binary_str.length
key_bits = hex_str.length * 4
```

Comment: You're not David Grayson! David doesn't look at all like that. For one, he always wears sunglasses.

Comment: You could also use [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) to write `"%0#{KEY_BITS}b" % 42 #=> "0000000000101010"`. (See [Kernel#sprintf](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for formatting.)

Answer (score 2):

The truth is, leading zeros are not part of the integer value. I mean, it's a little detail related to **representation** of this value, not the value itself. So if you want to preserve properties of representation, it may be best not to get to underlying values at all.

Luckily, hex<->binary conversion has one neat property: each hexadecimal digit exactly corresponds to 4 binary digits. So assuming you only get binary numbers that have number of digits divisible by 4 you can just construct two dictionaries for constructing back and forth:

```
# Hexadecimal part is easy
hex = [*'0'..'9', *'A'..'F']
# Binary... not much longer, but a bit trickier
bin = (0..15).map { |i| '%04b' % i }
```

Note the use of `String#%` operator, that formats the given value interpreting the string as `printf`-style format string.

Okay, so these are lists of "digits", 16 each. Now for the dictionaries:

```
hex2bin = hex.zip(bin).to_h
bin2hex = bin.zip(hex).to_h
```

Converting hex to bin with these is straightforward:

```
"DEADBEEF".each_char.map { |d| hex2bin[d] }.join
```

Converting back is not that trivial. I assume we have a "good number" that can be split into groups of 4 binary digits each. I haven't found a cleaner way than using `String#scan` with a "match every 4 characters" regex:

```
"10111110".scan(/.{4}/).map { |d| bin2hex[d] }.join
```

The procedure is mostly similar.

**Bonus task:** implement the same conversion disregarding my assumption of having only "good binary numbers", i. e. "110101".

**"I-should-have-read-the-docs" remark**: there is `Hash#invert` that returns a hash with all key-value pairs inverted.

Comment: it's curious that Ruby has no better way to do this conversion. It looks too verbose for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most straightforward solution I found that preserves leading zeros. To convert from hexadecimal to binary:

```rb
['DEADBEEF'].pack('H*').unpack('B*').first # => "11011110101011011011111011101111"
```

And from binary to hexadecimal:

```rb
['11011110101011011011111011101111'].pack('B*').unpack1('H*') # => "deadbeef"
```

Here you can find more information:

- `Array#pack`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-pack
- `String#unpack1` (similar to `unpack`): https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/String.html#method-i-unpack1